# Using video calling with CallKit and Sinch

Tags: ios, video, sinch, callkit

In sinch for IOS, the SinchCallKit example project can be used to create an audio call between two clients using callkit.

I have been trying to implement video calling in this project by changing it based on the [docs](https://www.sinch.com/docs/video/ios/#videocalling)
But I could use some pointers from a sinch veteran on wether I should:
modify the callkit example to include video calling,
modify the video calling example to include callkit.
And if it is even possible to combine callkit with video calling in sinch?

Answer (score -1):

No, you must open your own video call screen for calling. callkit not sink with sinch video call.
WhatsApp also open own app screen for call.